# How to jump to worksheet by typing partial name

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code I use to jump to sheets. It requires the exact name to typed in order to be found. Is there a way to have it jump to a sheet by typing in part of the sheet name?

For example, I have a large workbook with sheets named by their ID and currency. If I know the ID but not the currency I would like to be able to jump to the sheet.

[image]

My code:

```
Sub SelectSheet()
 Dim i As Variant
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 i = Application.InputBox("Enter worksheet name", "Select sheet")

'Cancel was pressed
 If i = False Or Trim(i) = "" Then Exit Sub

'Check if sheet exist
 On Error Resume Next
 Set ws = Sheets(i)
 On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox "Worksheet " & i & " not found!"
 Else
 Sheets(i).Select
 End If
 End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do a partial name match on the beginning of each sheet name. Adjust accordingly to fit your needs.

It works by matching the first `x` number of characters of each sheet name, where the value of `x` is determined by the number of characters you entered. You may need to handle case-conversion (e.g., converting the input to uppercase to remove case-sensitivity).

```
Sub SelectSheet()
  Dim Temp As Variant
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Temp = Application.InputBox("Enter worksheet name", "Select sheet")

  'Cancel was pressed
  If Temp = False Or Trim(Temp) = "" Then Exit Sub

  'Check if sheet exist
  On Error Resume Next

  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Left(Sheets(i).Name, Len(Temp)) = Temp Then  ' Match first letters
      Set ws = Sheets(i)                            ' Found it
    End If
  Next

  Set ws = Sheets(i)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Worksheet " & Temp & " not found!"
  Else
    ws.Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! When I run the script though with partial sheet name to test, I'm getting a "Subscript out of range" error.

Comment: figured it out. I changed the `Sheets(Temp).Select` to `ws.Select`, brillant thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure why that happened. Didn't on my test workbook, but I didn't have as many sheets. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.